# In C++, how can I delay a part of a program while continuing with the overall program?

Tags: c++, function, loops, sleep

Specifically, I'm trying to delay `a = 1 + 1` for 10 seconds. During this time, I would like the user to be able to input a value.

If the user doesn't respond in time, I would `a = 1 + 1` to make `a = 2` which will cause a bomb to go off and kill the user.

I tried using Sleep, but that halts the entire program and doesn't allow input from the user. How can I make the system preform both tasks at once, where for 10 seconds the user has a change to disable the bomb and make it not go off?

Comment: You need an event loop. You can't sleep the main thread and expect stuff to still happen.

Comment: 1) Please attach the code you're working with ([mcve]). 
2) If you're not using threads, this is probably impossible.

Comment: I have no code, was just hoping to get a direction that I should read more about. Thank you though, I'm going to look into threads.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the system perform both tasks at once?

The answer is Concurrency.

For example 2 threads, one for the first task, another for the second. And a raindrop of synchronization between them.

For further reading, I would like to recommend C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading by Anthony Williams.

Comment: There's *no* reason to complicate a program with threads to achieve this. You just need a timer and an event loop and/or a state machine.

Comment: It is one of many implementations, are there any restrictions about using concurrency or will it hurt OP? The first thing that comes to my mind after reading this question is definitely concurrency.

Comment: using threads *correctly* is *hard* - much, much harder than writing a correct single threaded program. Beware of threads - they *will* bite you in difficult to reproduce and debug ways eventually (usually at the most inconvenient time possible and at your largest customer). There *are* use cases for threads and they *can* be used correctly, just be careful and don't reach for them as the first solution unless you really have to; is my advice.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, no one says it is gonna be easy=) Especially debugging a deadlock or other extramarital son of Concurrency. But it is an experience and moreover, it is positive.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this depends on the situation.

If you're obtaining input through a method that blocks the current thread, like `std::cin` then a thread will probably necessary.

However, if you are obtaining input through a means that isn't blocking, then measuring time intervals would be a valid solution since you could simply exit as soon as the time limit has been reached. For this situation you could measure time via `std::chrono`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    auto start = clock::now();
    while (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(clock::now() - start).count() < 2000) {

    }
    std::cout << "Took two seconds to complete.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Sleep, nor you're forced to use multithreading to accomplish the task.

The simplest solution would use a 'message loop', and a tick/time-control function (i.e. GetTickCount, QueryPerformance, timeGetTime).

Concurrency is a little bit of an overkill for a not so complex task.